# HTTPS Certificate working on Chrome, not on Firefox

Tags: nginx, ssl

I've installed an SSL certificate in NginX, but it is not working on FireFox.

Beneath is my nginx config, I didn't wrote it myself and I'm especially worried about the localhost server which is pointing to different (faulty) certificates. But I'm not sure if these are used.

```
http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p327/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log  /opt/nginx/logs/access.log;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    # Make sure gzip does not lose large gzipped js or css files
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # Disable gzip for certain browsers.
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";

    server {
        listen    80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        access_log  logs/host.access.log;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
    server_name  yyyytest.xxx.nl;
        root /home/railsapps/yyyytest.xxx.nl/source/current/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env preview;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  wijziging.xxx.nl;
        rewrite      ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }

   server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  yyyy.xxx.nl;
        rewrite      ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }

   server {
        listen       443;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        access_log  logs/host.access.log;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        ssl                  on;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/yyyy_xxx_nl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/certs/positivessl.key;
    }

   server {
        listen       443;
        server_name  wijziging.xxx.nl yyyy.xxx.nl;
        root /home/railsapps/yyyy.xxx.nl/source/current/public;
        passenger_enabled on;

        ssl                  on;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/wijziging_xxx_nl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/certs/wijziging_xxx_nl.key;
    }
}
```

The certificate works in Chrome though..

Comment: Is this a self-signed certificate or issued by a 3rd party? If it is, who is the 3rd party who issued it?

Comment: I've got the certificate from CloudVPS, the certificate is called 'Comodo'

Comment: Every certificate should pass a series of protocols. You can check that on 3rd party websites like below. http://www.networking4all.com/en/support/tools/site+check/report/?fqdn=https%3A%2F%2Fwijziging.dmimpressions.nl%2F&protocol=https  http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://wijziging.dmimpressions.nl/. Probably you should follow the installation instructions here https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1365&nav=0,96,1,95

Comment: Sometimes build a chain crt can be painfull, find all the stapling files of comodo can be hard. But i found this amazing online tool for build your chain crt https://certificatechain.io/ You just have to upload the CRT provide by your registar ( e.g comodo )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Your config looks OK, but as deppfx says, it seems you haven't entered the chain of certificates back to Comodo to your certificate file. You do this by just appending the extra certificates to your .crt file (cert.pem in the example). The server certificate needs to be the first on the file, otherwise you'll get a mismatch between private and public keys.

#### Long version:

Every browser has a list of certificates that it trusts to issue other certificates. But often the certificate that you use will have an intermediate step - i.e. the root Comodo certificate has been used to sign an intermediate certificate, and that one has been used to issue your certificate. So the chain looks like this:

```
Root Comodo certificate -> Intermediate certificate -> Your certificate
```

So when Firefox connects, it sees that your certificate exists and has been signed by someone claiming to be Comodo. But since Firefox doesn't have the intermediate certificate, it can't verify that that is, in fact, Comodo, and so it can't trust your certificate.

When you add the intermediate certificate to your configuration, Firefox will receive both your certificate and the intermediate one. Firefox can then check that the intermediate certificate was really signed by the root cert that Firefox has, and then it will trust your certificate.

#### Step by step:

1. You already have your own certificate in the file /etc/ssl/certs/wijziging_xxx.nl.crt.
2. Download the intermediate and the root certificate according to https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1365&nav=0,96,1,95
3. Add those certificates to wiziging_xxx.nl.crt, like this:

   `cat /path/to/intermediate.crt >> /etc/ssl/certs/wijziging_xxx.nl.crt`

   `cat /path/to/root.crt >> /etc/ssl/certs/wijziging_xxx.nl.crt`
4. Restart nginx.

Comment: I think I understand your answer, but I don't know what to do next code-wise. Do the two nginx ssl servers in my config need to point to different ssl certificates?

Comment: I'd be really glad if you could help me in chat or something, because I need to get this working asap. Can I pm you somewhere?

Comment: I added some step-by-step info; unfortunately I don't have the possibility to help you in chat today.

Comment: Managed to solve it! I was using `cat` to bundle the files, but didn't know that after a few tries all certificates would 'add up' in the bundle, after removing it and retrying it worked

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, it really shed some light on the whole certificate chaining configuration. My config is now using the bundled crt and the key of my own certificate.

Comment: I hope this doesn't come across as me being superior - but I think it would pay off if you spend some time learning some more unix basics. Using cat is something you will need to know how it works, and there are a lot of things that will make your life easier that you probably just don't know about yet. I think if you just google for "basic unix course" you'll find about half a gazillion pages that will help you a great deal. Also, there's our sister site http://unix.stackexchange.com that I think will have some content you will find useful.

Comment: You're totally right, I should do that.. The only things I learned are the things that I needed in the past (`git` `vi`, and some basic directory stuff). Lately I am indeed using more and more unix commands.. Now I only need to find the time to learn these basics, but like I said, you do have a point here..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing a Root CA (Certificate Authority) & also the certificate Issuing path.

[image: Bad Certificate]

[image: Good Certificate]

Refer to Bob's answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/452069/124651)